# How to tag random 5 friends in comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a facebook lottery, and I have with the Facebook API to tag five people randomly in comment.
I looking fot it many time in google, but I don't find any solution.

Comment: That’s against Platform Policies – every part of the message that you post on behalf of a user must be a 100% generated by the user; and that of course includes tagging of friends.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if they _consent_, they must actually _create_ every bit of the message themselves, with no interference by your app whatsoever.